# User agents for iOS - ipad, iphone, ipad is false while it should be true

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ipad, user-agent

I'm using user agent to check whether the visiting user is coming from an ipad or iphone.

Im using the following to check so:

```
var isIOSapp = false;
var isIOS_Ipad;
var isIOS_Ipod;
var isIOS_Phone;

/* Detect if running on iOS */
function getMobileOperatingSystem() {
  var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

  if( userAgent.match( /iPad/i ) || userAgent.match( /iPhone/i ) || userAgent.match( /iPod/i ) )
  {
    return 'iOS';

  }
  if( userAgent.match( /iPod/i ) )
  {
    return 'iOSIpod';

  }
  if( userAgent.match( /iPad/i ) )
  {
    return 'iOSIpad';

  }
  if( userAgent.match( /iPhone/i ) || userAgent.match( /iPod/i ) )
  {
    return 'iOSPhone';

  }
}

if(getMobileOperatingSystem() == "iOS") {
    isIOSapp = true;
}
if(getMobileOperatingSystem() == "iOSIpod") {
    isIOS_Ipod = true;
}
if(getMobileOperatingSystem() == "iOSIpad") {
    isIOS_Ipad = true;
}
if(getMobileOperatingSystem() == "iOSPhone") {
    isIOS_Phone = true;
}
```

When visiting from both Ipad and Iphone I get the following:

```
isIOSapp = true
isIOS_Ipad = undefined
isIOS_Phone = undefined
isIOS_Ipod = undefined
```

So it seems something is triggered in the first if condition.

What is going wrong since none of the individual devices `isIOS_Ipad` `isIOS_Phone` `isIOS_Ipod` is turning up = true?

You would think atleast one should be = true for `isIOSapp` to trigger = true

Comment: Why do you expect anything other than `isIOSapp` to be set given the code you wrote? Inside `getMobileOperatingSystem`, you will always return `iOS` before any of the other conditions can be evaluated.

Comment: oh god, brain damaged - I see what you mean! ugh!